# Connecting to Oracle database from PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have an Oracle database that I am trying to connect to.

For some reason when I try the following code:

```
<?php
    include "header.php";
    // simply attempt to connect to the database
    /* If you are connecting to the Oracle database, the credentials are as follows: 
     * Username: ********
     * Password: ********
     * Hostname: **********
     * Port: 1521
     * Service name: ***********
    */
    $oracleConnect = true;
    if ($oracleConnect)
    {
        echo 'Attempting connection...<br>';
        $connection = null;
        try
        {
            $connection = oci_connect('user',
                'pass',
                'user@//hostname:1521/dbname');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        if (!$connection)
        {
            echo '<p>Something is wrong.</p>';
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        // if the connection has been established
        else
        {
            // tell the user and close it (this is a test)
            echo 'Connection established!!';
            oci_close($connection);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $connection = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
        echo ($connection) ? 'Database connection successful!' : 'Could not connect.';
    }
    include "footer.php";
?>
```

When I try the above code, I get the "Attempting connection..." to print, but nothing else. It is supposed to print something else regardless. What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Echo something in the `try` to make sure the process is entered. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `user@` part of your connection string. I don't think that's necessary as `oci_connect` has a user name parameter. I could be wrong, I've never used oracle from php before, but [the docs on oci connections](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) would also seem to indicate that:

> To use the Easy Connect naming method, PHP must be linked with Oracle 10g or greater Client libraries. The Easy Connect string for Oracle 10g is of the form: [//]host_name[:port][/service_name]. From Oracle 11g, the syntax is: [//]host_name[:port][/service_name][:server_type][/instance_name]. Service names can be found by running the Oracle utility lsnrctl status on the database server machine.

Also `oci_connect` does not throw an exception as far as I can tell so your try/catch is useless unless you planned on throwing your own when it returns `false`.

Comment: OK, so I took out the `user@` part, as well as the try/catch block, and it still does not work! Here is the test site: http://dinotator.biokdd.org/ResearchProject/dbConnect.php

Comment: Turn on display_errors as @JayBlanchard suggested in his comment and see if there are any... also when there is not connection try `print_r($e)` instead of your formatting just to see... you could have something screwed up there. because its never making it to the include for the footer... meaning there is an error thats halting processing. And that is the most likely place.

Comment: oci_connect() was "undefined"! 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /home1/biokddor/public_html/dinotator/ResearchProject/dbConnect.php on line 17`

Comment: Ahh you must not have the `oci` extension installed.